# use chained through time pattern,why the nextTask's value always is null?

Tags: optaplanner

I have a project that is similar to the task assigning project which uses the chained through time pattern. I have difficulty comparator that expect the tasks that must be finished earlier. but the test result shows me nextTask's value always is null and the task's move was not orderly by the task's id.
the StartTimeUpdatingVariableListener code image url:

[image: refernce]